# How to use Hot Module Replacement with Electron

Tags: reactjs, webpack, electron, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr

I’d like to use HMR with my React Electron app. How would I do that? Do I need web pack? How do I integrate it with Electron?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use a webpack config just like you would with a normal web app.

The settings depend on wether you are using react-hot-loader 2 or 3 (beta)

You then set the src attribute in your index.html file to wherever your webpack dev server is serving the bundle from.
Usually: localhost:8080/bundlename.js

Here is the walkthrough for react-hot-loader 2:
http://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/

Comment: Ok, I’ll try that when I get a chance